# Function to disable a button if a given input text doesn't contain at least n characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with this function

```
function block_button(min){

    current=$(this).val().length;
    if(current>=min){
        $(this).next().css('opacity','1');
    }else{
        $(this).next().css('opacity','0.5');  
    }
}

$('input').keyup(function(){
    block_button.apply(4,this);
});
```

The purpose of the function is to count the length of the string while user writes and then disable or enable the button below (I changed only the opacity so this is a "visual" disable but it's intended).

The function has a number for parameter and this is the minimum string length to enable the button. The problem is that nothing happens when I reach 4 characters.

How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: I'd start with some basic debugging: Does your function get called at all? What are the values of `min` and `current` at this time? Use the dev tools of your browser and set some break points or add some `console.log`s.

Comment: I just verified that. The function works because i changed it removing the parameter and giving a min=4. The problem must be here     block_button.apply(4,this); but i can't figure out how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `$(this)` directly inside a function. Instead you should put it inside a variable before you call the function, and then use that variable inside the function:

```js
function block_button(min){

    current=$this.val().length;
    if(current>=min){
        $this.next().css('opacity','1');
    }else{
        $this.next().css('opacity','0.5');  
    }
}

$('input').keyup(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    block_button(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button>Button</button>
```

You should instead have the button disabled by default, and then if the user enters more than X characters in the input-field, have the disabled attribut removed. If the user then deletes characters, add the attribute back again:

```js
function disableButton(min) {

  current = $this.val().length;
  if (current >= min) {
    $this.next().removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $this.next().attr("disabled", "");
  }
}

$('input').keyup(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  disableButton(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button disabled>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ugeshgupta000/5grrzdnn/1/

```
function block_button(elem, min){
  current=elem.val().length;
  if(current>=min){
  elem.next().css('opacity','1');
  }else{
  elem.next().css('opacity','0.5');
  }
}

$('input').keyup(function(){
   block_button($(this), 4);
});
```